# Parallel LTC3127 based software controlled supercapacitor charger

Tags: microcontroller, surface-mount, supercapacitor, buck-boost

I am trying to charge 3 supercapacitors rated for 2.7VDC-300F connected in parallel, giving a total of 900F@2.7V. The IC I am trying to use is the LTC3127 from Analog Devices(Linear Technologies). I have been through the IC datasheet but as a beginner, some of the things are still confusing to me.

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3127fa.pdf

I want to fully control this IC using a microcontroller such as the Raspberry Pi or ATtiny or STM32F0. By fully control I meant: enable or disable(on or off) the IC, set the programmable input current limit(0.2A-1A) and set the output voltage limit(1.8V-5.25V). All this through software on the micro at 3.3V logic level.

Typical Application (Datasheet):
[image: Typical Application Schematic]

This typical application schematic shows the charging of 2 supercaps in series. But, I want my bank in parallel. Furthermore, I want to stack this same IC 3 times in parallel to allow more charging current to the supercaps when needed. Also, controlled by software to allow different charging current through: IC1(min) or IC1+IC2 or IC1+IC2+IC3(max) on (0.2A-3A) range.

Questions:

1. What type of resistors or RC filters I would need on the MODE, SHDN, PROG and FB pins for connecting them to a micro. For protection of the IO pins on both sides as well as precise control.
2. Should I need to do any value modifications to any of this typical schematic components for better reliability and performance in terms of charging the super capacitor bank mentioned above?
3. What characteristics of an SMD inductor should I consider to provide better reliability, less heating and overall good performance headroom?
4. I am planning to use NP0/C0G MLCC for all the capacitors mentioned in the schematic. Will this be a good approach? Would tantalum SMD caps be more useful in any way for this case?
5. How should I go about stacking 3 of this IC together? Should I share the typical passives needed? What about the control side of things? Surely want to control 3 of the ICs individually.

Comment: The word "programmable" here just means you can set it when you design the circuit (by the choice of resistor between PROG and ground). If you want to be able to control the current limit with a microcontroller, you need to either use a different chip or do something with a digital potentiometer.

Comment: `I have been through the IC datasheet but as a beginner, some of the things are still confusing to me.` Datasheets are extremely straightforward and unambiguous. If they weren't, people wouldn't purchase their products. What are curious about? You're telling us what you want to do but you haven't mentioned where in the datasheet you're confused. Also `This typical application schematic shows the charging of 2 supercaps in series.` No, that's not right. Those two capacitors are parallel because they share the same node. If they were in series, there wouldn't be a path between them.

Comment: *"I want to stack this same IC 3 times in parallel to allow more charging current"* Voltage regulators can not be 'just' put in parallel. Find a regulator which can deliver more current.

Comment: @KingDuken:  If C1 and C2 are the supercaps being charged, they are indeed in series by my definition.

Comment: @PeterBennett No, they are not in series **by definition**. Elements in series have exactly the same current, regardless of the voltage across them, by definition. As long as any current can flow through the 100k resistors then the capacitors are not strictly in series. However, if the current through the resistors is negligible then the capacitors are **effectively** in series.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: Yes - perhaps I should have said the two capacitor/resistor pairs are in series.  In any case, the capacitors are definitely not connected in parallel.

Comment: @Hearth Yes, sorry I overlooked the current sinking on the PROG pin. Can you suggest a good high quality SMD digital Potentiometer that would be good for this application, and any hookup guide for the potentiometer to the micro?

Comment: @KingDuken But why this 100K resistors pass through in the circuit? Isn't it possible to just hook up my 900F bank directly tto Vout after the FB resistor network?

Comment: @Oldfart I tried to find some other regulators which can work with supercapacitors but with higher current limits. But then again, they are not specific for this particular charging only task. Most of them have bidirectional backup power system which would be out of my use case. Even if I use bidirectional dc/dc converter I would need the converter to operate from ultra low voltage like 0.3V for allowing me to take out most of the energy from the supercaps. If you have any component in mind that would be suitable, please suggest.